# jquery Ajax call seems to work only once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a bunch of images that people can click on a heart on top to "love" or "unlove". I figured out how to make it work with Ajax / jQuery but for some reason, it only works `once`.

The image underneath has a link to it, too ...so I need to do a preventDefault on the heart div overlayed on top. Which again, works once.

The structure is like:

```
<a href="...">
<div class="image">
  <img src="...">
    <div class="love-response love"></div>
</div>
</a>
```

So if they click the heart, it works correctly ...but if they click it again, it then goes to the link of the image underneath. If they however reload the page after clicking the link, they can again click it and it works to unlove it. But then again, if they click again without reloading it goes to the image underneath again.

I think it has to do with the fact that the json data is returned and then updates the content, but on further clicks it somehow doesn't do a preventDefault anymore.

What could be wrong here?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('.love').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var id = $(this).data("id");
  $("#love-response-" + id).hide();
  $("#love-waiting-" + id).show();
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://www.domain.com/love.php?id=" + id,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(json) {
        if(json.valid == 1) {

            $("#love-waiting-" + id).hide();
            $("#love-response-" + id).replaceWith(json.message);
            $("#love-response-" + id).show();

        }
        else {
            $("#love-waiting-" + id).hide();
            $("#love-response-" + id).replaceWith(json.message);
            $("#love-response-" + id).show();
        }
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {

        $("#love-waiting-" + id).hide();
        $("#love-response-" + id).html('ERROR');
    },
    timeout: 15000
  });
});
});
```

The json is pretty basic. It's either:

```
{
"valid":"0",
"message":"<div class=\"love-response love\" id=\"love-response-782\" data-id=\"782\"><span class=\"icon love-black\"><\/span><\/div>"
}
```

or

```
{
"valid":"1",
"message":"<div class=\"love-response love\" id=\"love-response-782\" data-id=\"782\"><span class=\"icon love-red\"><\/span><\/div>"
}
```

I really feel like the problem is somehow with the preventDefault not executing anymore after it received the response back from json.

Comment: Have you tried using this:
$(".love").live("click",function(){
      //Your code here
});

Comment: @IgorIlic [*"As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated."*](http://api.jquery.com/live/). I would not recommend that. `.on()` is recommended by jQuery.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

delegate the click event handler to sth. thats always in your DOM
as the .love is manipulated dom (loaded via ajax) so it triggers only once because the element was not there when the script was executed

simply change

```
 $('.love').click(function (e) {
```

to

```
 $(document).on('click','.love',function (e) {
```

Answer (score 3):

When you do this:

```
$('.love').click(function (e) {
```

You're attaching that function to the click event of those matched elements.  Not to the *selector*, but to the elements which are selected *at that time*.  Then when you do this:

```
$("#love-response-" + id).replaceWith(json.message);
```

You *remove* those elements and add *new* ones.  Those new ones don't have click events associated with them.  The old ones did.

You can correct this by using [event delegation](http://publicvoidlife.blogspot.com/2014/03/on-on-or-event-delegation-explained.html).  What this means is binding to the click event of some common parent element and filtering the origin of the click based on some selector.  At its simplest, it would look like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.love', function (e) {
    // your code
});
```