# Why delete Ajax request works only once on Firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I use jQuery Ajax request to access PHP script where i delete data from my MySql database like this

```
 $(document).on("click", "#del_mon", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost/test/del.php"
  });
  location.reload(true);
});
```

`#del_mon` is my button.

This code only works once on Firefox, but not after. I tried this on Chrome (Version 80.0.3987.122) and Edge (Version 80.0.361.62), works multiple times on both. Firefox version i use is 73.0.1 and is up to date. I use Ajax request to add and read data from my database as well and that works fine on Firefox.

I get no errors in my console.

I tried to find solution and i changed my click functions from this

```
$("#del_mon").click(function(e) {});
```

to this

```
$(document).on("click", "#del_mon", function(e) {});
```

As shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29010603/jquery-ajax-call-seems-to-work-only-once/29010696) stack post. But this does not work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reloading the page may be cancelling the AJAX request that was about to be sent.

You should do the reload when the response is received, not immediately after sending the AJAX request.

```
$(document).on("click", "#del_mon", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost/test/del.php",
    success: function() {
      location.reload(true);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Yes, that's it. I can't believe i miss that. Does this mean that Chrome and Edge process request faster that Firefox?

Comment: Maybe, or they just don't cancel it.

Answer (score -1):

You should try to make an action just before your call has been done.

```
 $(document).on("click", "#del_mon", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost/test/del.php",
    success: function() {
     location.reload(true);
    }
  });

});
```

As @Barmar said before, but I would recommend to use `done` and `catch` for a future iteration, just to know if the problem is in the call or not.

```
 async function getData(){
  const data =  await $.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost/test/del.php',
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'json'
});
return data;
}
 $(document).on("click", "#del_mon", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  getData().then((response) => {
   console.log("done ",response);
   location.reload(true);

  }).catch((error) => {
    //console.log("fail ", error);
  });


});
```

Comment: Why wrap it in a Promise when jQuery provides an `error` property on the `ajax` config?

Comment: A promise could help you to write smaller and compact functions, small functions are easier to unit test, or even if we use for example fail instead of the property error of ajax, we would be able to handle more than one callback option. [here my reference](https://blog.revathskumar.com/2016/06/why-i-prefer-ajax-promise.html)

Comment: sorry, I simply can't give an upvote to this. This is pretty much just Barmar's answer with an unnecessary refactor suggestion..